# Essentialy bounded functions with compact support are locally integrable and satisfy aditional condition?

Tags: functional-analysis, solution-verification, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure, supremum-and-infimum

Consider arbitrary elements $1 \leqslant p < \infty$ and $0 < \lambda \leqslant n$. Furthermore, during this post I considered the usual Lebesgue measure over $\mathbb R^n$ and I denote the Lebesgue measure of a set by $|\cdot|$.

My goal is to show that every essentialy bounded function $f$ with compact support satisfies the following two conditions:

$$ f \in L^p_{\text{loc}}(\mathbb R^n) \quad \text{ and } \quad \sup_{x \in \mathbb R^n, \, r > 0} r^{-\lambda} \int_{B(x,r)} |f(y)|^p \, dy < \infty. $$

**My attempt.** I was able to show that $f \in L^p_{\text{loc}}(\mathbb R^n)$ in the following way: for every compact set $K \subset \mathbb R^n$ we have that

$$ \int_K |f(y)|^p \, dy \leqslant \| f \|_{L^\infty(\mathbb R^n)}^p \int_K 1 \, dy = \| f \|_{L^\infty(\mathbb R^n)}^p |K| < \infty, $$

since $f$ is essentially bounded by hypothesis and since compact sets have finite Lebesgue measure.

Therefore, all that's left to prove is that $f$ also satisfies the second property. Note that to show that $f$ is locally $p-$integrable everything I needed to use was the essential boundedness of $f$, but such simplicity doesn't occur for the second property. Let us see why this is the case: simple calculations tell us that

$$ \sup_{x \in \mathbb R^n, \, r > 0} r^{-\lambda} \int_{B(x,r)} |f(y)|^p \, dy \leqslant \sup_{r > 0} r^{-\lambda} \| f \|_{L^\infty(\mathbb R^n)}^p |B(x,r)| = \sup_{r > 0} r^{n-\lambda} \| f \|_{L^\infty(\mathbb R^n)}^p |B(0,1)|, $$

and the right-hand side supremum is not necessarily finite for $0 < \lambda \leqslant n$. So I believe that I shall use the fact that $f$ has compact support to prove this property but I am having a hard time trying to do so.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: Since $f$ has compact support, you can find $R > 0$ such that $\text{supp}\;f \subset B(0,R)$.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @stange . I agree with that, but I don't see how that helps in showing that $f$ also has the second property. Perhaps you can elaborate a little bit more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what you essentially want to show that $L^\infty_c(\mathbb{R}^n)\hookrightarrow L^{p,\lambda}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ for $0 < \lambda \leq n$, where the latter space is the Morrey space. Your calculations already show that $L^\infty_c(\mathbb{R}^n)\hookrightarrow L^{p,n}(\mathbb{R}^n)$. Next, we prove that $L^{p,n}(\mathbb{R}^n) \cap L^\infty_c(\mathbb{R}^n)\hookrightarrow L^{p,\lambda}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ for all $0 < \lambda < n$. 
Let $R>0$ such that $\text{supp}\;f\subset B(0,R)$. Then for all $r\in (0,R)$
$$ \int_{B(x,r)}\vert f \vert^p\;dx = r^{n} r^{-n}\int_{B(x,r)}\vert f \vert^p \;dx \leq r^{\lambda} R^{n-\lambda} r^{-n}\int_{B(x,r)}\vert f \vert^p \;dx.$$
Thus,
$$ \sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}^n, r > 0} r^{-\lambda}\int_{B(x,r)}\vert f \vert^p \;dx \leq R^{n-\lambda}\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}^n, r > 0} r^{-n}\int_{B(x,r)}\vert f \vert^p \;dx,  $$
which concludes the proof. 
More generally, you can show that
$$ L^{q,\mu}(\Omega) \hookrightarrow L^{p,\lambda}(\Omega)$$
for $1\leq p \leq q <\infty$, $\lambda, \mu \geq 0$ with $\frac{\lambda - n}{p} \leq \frac{\mu-n}{q}$, and $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ is a bounded domain.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have one question: I understand that I've shown that the inclusion holds for $\lambda = n$ and that you're trying to use this fact in order to show that the inclusion also holds for every other $\lambda \in (0,n)$. Also, I understand the inequality you provided for all $r \in (0,R)$. I just don't understand how you conclude from this that $$ \sup_{ x \in \mathbb R^n, \, r > 0} r^{-\lambda} \int_{B(x,r)} |f|^p \, dx \leqslant R^{n-\lambda} \, \sup_{x \in \mathbb R^n, \, r > 0} r^{-n} \int_{B(x,r)} |f|^p \, dx. $$ Are you using the support in this conclusion?

Comment: Yes, I used that $\int_{B(x,r)} \vert f \vert^p\;dx = \int_{B(x,r)\cap B(0,R)} \vert f \vert^p\;dx$. That is the reason why it was sufficient to consider $r\in(0,R)$.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is the definition of support you're using?

Comment: $\text{supp}\;f = \overline{\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n: f(x) \neq 0\}}$.

Comment: But of course, maybe one should work with the essential support, which doesn't change the argument.